# How to create custom request in Jmeter for API request body

Tags: api, groovy, jmeter

I need to generate multiple orders(1-10)randomly and each order contains products (1-20) randomly.
Item are sent from a csv file.How can I customize request body to acheive this in Jmeter?

```
{
  "multipleOrders": [
    {
      "orderId": "12345678",
      "products": [
        {
          "productId": "1",
          "value": [
            {
              "item":"1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "productId": "2",
          "value": [
            {
              "item":"2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
     {
      "orderId": "98765432",
      "products": [
                    {
          "productId": "4",
          "value": [
            {
              "item":"4"
            
            }
          ]
        }
     ]
    }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sending random number of items is what you should be really doing because tests need to be [repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability) and given each request would assume random hence different number of parameters you won't be able to re-run the same test once again in order to troubleshoot the issue.

Whatever.

It's not very possible to provide a comprehensive answer without seeing how the "items" are organized in your CSV file.

You can read the file in Groovy like:

```
def lines = new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines()
```

and you can create the JSON in Groovy using [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) class

```
def payload = [:]

def multipleOrders = []

1.upto(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(1, 20), index -> {
    def order = [:]
    def lineFromCsv = lines.get(index as int)
    order.put('orderId', lineFromCsv.split(',')[0])
    //etc.

    multipleOrders.add(order)
})

payload.put('multipleOrders', multipleOrders)

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

Amend the above snippet to match your requirements.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)